# How to use secret-tool in cronjob with non-root user?

Tags: bash, cron, seahorse

I use this command in my bash script.

```bsh
somePassw=$(/usr/bin/secret-tool lookup some-login $someLogin 2>secret-tool.log)
```

It works great in command line. But if the script is run from crontab I see next messages in the log:

```
secret-tool.log:
(secret-tool:6289): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:02:01.285: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
secret-tool: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

The same errors I see in terminal if I enter `sudo -E secret-tool lookup...`
But I created my crobtab job without root permissions. How can I get rid of these errors?
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (gdm3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "You can't".

`secret-tool` uses the `$DISPLAY` variable to find the GUI to display stuff.

Running through `cron`, there's no GUI.

One *could* copy the `$DISPLAY` variable from the GUI environment to the cronjob ( and read `man xhost`), but that would make `secret-tool`'s prompts appear on your screen, which defeats the purpose of `cron`.

Also, because `secret-tool` deals with Authentication, it *might* detect and forbid this situation, or *might* need other environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.